# Reorder Bar Chart Output in ggplot2 when using as.factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was hoping someone could help.

I have a DF as follows:

```
Year   Winner
1930  Uruguay    
1934  Italy    
1938  Italy    
1950  Uruguay    
1954  Germany FR    
1958  Brazil    
1962  Brazil    
1966 England    
1970  Brazil    
....
```

and so on

What I want to do is create a bar chart with ggplot2, but reorder it so the country with the highest number of winners comes first.

The code I've used to generate my current graph is:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=as.factor(Winner), fill=as.factor(Winner) )) + 
geom_bar() + 
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I know there's something about reorder but I can't get it to work with the as.factor argument.

Thanks

Comment: Given that `Winner` is all character strings you shouldn't need to use `as.factor` when making the plot.  Have you tried removing that and then attempting `reorder`?

Answer (score 2):

I got around this problem using forcats

```
    require(forcats)
    ggplot(data, aes(fct_infreq(Winner),  fill=as.factor(Winner))) +
    geom_bar()+
    theme(legend.position = "none")
```